# Rails - Manipulating the returned objects in an ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

So I have the following simplified models and associations:

```
class Barber < User
    has_many :barber_styles, inverse_of: :barber
end

class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class BarberStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :barber, inverse_of: :barber_styles
    belongs_to :style
    delegate :name, to: :style
end
```

If I wanted to make a query based on all `BarberStyle`'s that belong to a specific `Barber`, is there a way I can include the name of the associated `Style`?

I want to use a line something like:

```
BarberStyle.joins(:barber).where(barber: 109).include(:style)
```

So I'd be able to access an associated `style.name`. But I don't think a line like this exists.

I know I could just use `map` to build an array of my own objects, but I have to use a similar query with many different models, and don't want to do a bunch of extra work if it's not necessary.

In one of my previous projects, I was able to render json with the following lines:

```
@colleges = College.includes(:sports).where(sports: { gender: "male" })
render json: @colleges, include: :sports
```

But I don't want to render json in this case.

**Edit:**

I don't really have any unincluded associations to show, but I'll try to elaborate further.

All I'm trying to do is have extra associated models/fields aggregated to each `BarberStyle` result within my ActiveRecord Relation query.

In an attempt to make this less confusing, here is an example of the type of data I want to pass into my JS view:

```
[
  #<BarberStyle 
    id: 1, 
    barber_id: 116, 
    style_id: 91,
    style: { name: "Cool Hairstyle" }
    >, 
  #<BarberStyle 
    id: 2, 
    barber_id: 97, 
    style_id: 92,
    style: { name: "Cooler Hairstyle" }
    >,
  etc...
]
```

The reason I want the data formatted this way is because I can't make any queries on associated models in my JS view (without an AJAX call to the server).

I had very similarly formatted data when I did `render json: @colleges, include: :sports` in the past. This gave me a collection of `Colleges` with associated `Sport` models aggregated to each `College` result. I don't want to build json in this fashion for my current situation, as it will complicate a few things. But I suppose that's a last resort.

I'm not sure if there's a way to structure an ActiveRecord query where it adds additional fields to the results, but I feel like it should, so here I am looking for it. Haven't found anything in the docs, but then again there is sooooo much left out of those.

Comment: have you tried setting up a [`has_many` *through* relation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)? It seems to fit perfectly to your situation...

Comment: I actually do have a `has_many :styles, through: :barber_styles` association set for my `Barber` model. But I excluded that because I didn't think it'd be relevant. I'm trying to query BarberStyles and include the associated Style or the name of the associated Style within the BarberStyle objects that the collection returns.

Comment: ok cool, then please add all of the info about your relationships to your question, it is very relevant

Comment: @Doug can you please update your question and share the associations between the AR appearing on your codebase?

Answer (score 1):

Doug as far as I understand your code, `BarberStyle` must be a joining model between `Barber` and `Style`. You mentioned in your comment that you removed the `has_many :styles, through: :barber_styles` from your `Barber` model because you thought that it wasn't relevant. That's not true, it's exactly the point that would help you to achieve your goal. Add this relation again then you can do something like this:

```
barber = Barber.includes(:styles).where(barber: {id: 109})
barber.styles.each { |style| puts style.name }
```

Since `barber.styles` is a collection, I added a loop between all the possible styles you can have. But, from that, you can use your data as you feel like, looping through it or any other way you want.

Hope to have helped!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, perhaps I wasn't clear. I'm trying to get the style data to be contained within the collection of BarberStyles without having to query for the name of the style separately. I'll be passing this collection to JavaScript where it won't have access to the server. I do still have the `has_many through` association in my code, but I just didn't include it here. I suppose I could just render json and build the objects myself, but my question was whether or not there's a way to get those Style fields included in the BarberStyle objects returned in the query collection

Comment: Can't you add a ```has_many :baber_styles``` to you ```Style``` model? If you want to get ```Style````data from your ```BarberStyle``` model, i think that´s the way to go.

Comment: No, I'm making the query within my controller and then rendering the results to a JavaScript view. Then within my JavaScript view I want to loop through the BarberStyle objects and then grab the name of the style they belong to. I cannot access the server from my JS view unless I do an AJAX call. And this is the only way to grab associated models with Rails - with a query to the database. I need to have the style fields within the objects in the collection to be able to get that info from my JavaScript view.

Answer (score 0):

First off, in your case `inverse_of` does not accomplish anything, since you are setting the default values. Remove that.

Secondly, it seems you need to better understand the concept of HABTM relationships. 
Using [`has many through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is generally a good idea since you can add data and logic to the model in the middle.

It ideally suits your case, so you should set it up like this:

```
class Barber < User
  has_many :barber_styles
  has_many :styles, through: :barber_styles
end

class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :barber_styles
  has_many :barbers, through: :barber_styles
end

class BarberStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :barber
  belongs_to :style
end
```

Now it is an easy task to get the styles of a given barber. Just do this:

```
barber = Barber.find(1)
barber.styles
# => AR::Collection[<#Style name:'Cool Hairstyle'>,<#Style name:'Cooler Hairstyle'>]
```

Rails automatically uses the BarberStyle model in between to find the styles of a certain barber.
I assume this covers your need, if you have extra information stored *only* in BarberStyle, let me know.

Comment: as an extra note, nothing is added when you solely want to query `BarberStyle`. Go directly for `Style`.